# Exclude links from preg_match_all/foreach that are commented out

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function in wordpress which finds links and changes them.

```
//FINDS ALL IMAGE LINKS
preg_match_all('/\S*\bwww\.tradingview\.com\S*/', $data['post_content'], $matches); 


//FOR EACH IMAGE LINK IN THE CONTENT...
foreach( $matches[0] as $imgURL ):
```

I'm trying to make it so that it ignores any link that is commented out like this:

`<!-- https://www.tradingview.com -->`

I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I'm very new to web dev so apologies if I've left anything out.

Edit: I made a typo and added the ! in the first part of the comment

Edit: Here's the rest of my code, including the print statement.

```
function customPostSave($data , $postarr) {

//      INCLUDES REQUIRED WP FILES
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

//FINDS ALL IMAGE LINKS
preg_match_all('/\S*\bwww\.tradingview\.com\S*/', $data['post_content'], $matches);
echo '<pre>', print_r($matches[0]), '</pre>';

//FOR EACH IMAGE LINK IN THE CONTENT...
foreach( $matches[0] as $imgURL ):

//      REMOVES ALL SPACES AROUND THE URL
$imgURL = trim($imgURL);

// STORE ORIGINAL URL
$imgURLoriginal = $imgURL;

//      PREPARES FILE INFORMATIONS
$file_array = array();
$file_array['name'] = basename($imgURL);
if( !preg_match('/(\.png)$/i', $imgURL) ) $file_array['name'] .= '.png';
$file_array['tmp_name'] = download_url($imgURL);

//      DOWNLOADS THE IMAGE AND UPLOADS IT LOCALLY
$id = media_handle_sideload($file_array, $postarr['post_ID']);
$localURL = wp_get_attachment_url($id);

//      GRABS THE POST TAGS
$tags = wp_get_object_terms($postarr['post_ID'], 'post_tag');
$imgTags = array();

if( !empty($tags) ):
foreach( $tags as $tag ):
array_push($imgTags, $tag->name);
endforeach;
endif;

//      REPLACES THE IMAGE URL IN THE CONTENT, WITH <IMG> TAGS WITH SPECIFIC STYLES
$data['post_content'] = str_replace(
$imgURL,
'<!-- '.$imgURLoriginal.' -->
<p style="text-align:center"><a href="' . $localURL . '" class="everlightbox-trigger"><img src="' . $localURL . '" alt="' . implode($imgTags, ', ') . '" style="width:100%;"></a></p>',
$data['post_content']
);

endforeach;

return $data;

} add_filter('wp_insert_post_data' , 'customPostSave' , '99', 2);
```

Comment: Are these actual image tags you're finding, like `<img src="www.tradingview.com/image.jpg" />`?

Comment: Not necessarily. It finds links based on their containing www.tradingview.com/, although the links to which the function is designed to apply to do contain actual images. i.e. https://www.tradingview.com/i/YbZCEpl3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to provide you with a good answer due to lack of infomation. You should update your question with output from `echo '<pre>', print_r($matches[0]), '</pre>';` so we know what data you are working with.

If all start with "<--", you can do it like this:

```
foreach($matches[0] as $imgURL) {
    if(substr($imgURL, 0, 3) !== "<--") {
        echo $imgURL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'm not sure what that does, where to put it, or how I would run it to give you output. Very noob here, sorry.

Turns out my post had the wrong info, the first part of the comment starts with <!-- (instead of just <--). So I modified the code a bit like this: 

`foreach($matches[0] as $imgURL) {
    if(substr($imgURL, 0, 4) !== "<!--") {
        echo $imgURL;
    }
}`

However when I update the post, it is still applying to <!-- tradingview.... -->

I can't find anywhere that is explaining that echo <pre> item you mentioned.

Comment: Just type print_r($matches[0]); after your preg_match_all-function. <pre> will just make it easyer to read, <pre> is a html-tag

Comment: We need the output of the print_r(). We will be able to see what data $matches[0] contain

Comment: Sorry I'm missing something here. I did not write this code by the way. Where do I find output?

Comment: You need to execute the code before you see the output